# How can I capture stdout/stderr in a file but still see it in my console?

Tags: shell-script, shell, stdout, stderr

I'm using bash script on AMazon Linux.  When I want to redirect stderr and stdout to a file, I can run

```
./my_process.pl &>/tmp/out.txt
```

Is there a way I can redirect this output to a file and continue to see it on the console (in my shell)?  How is this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by using `tee`:

```
/my_process.pl 2>&1 | tee /tmp/out.txt
```

Note that using `&>file` for redirecting both standard output and standard error to a file is an extension to the POSIX standard that is accepted by some shells.  It is safer to use `>file 2>&1`. In this case, `&>` can not be used at all since we're not redirecting to a file.

In `bash`, one may also do

```
/my_process.pl |& tee /tmp/out.txt
```

which is equivalent of the above.  In `ksh93`, `|&` means something *completely* different though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `script` commands this will store both `stdin` and `stdout` in a file called `typescript`.