# How to stdin with tee or other kind of pipes or redirection of outputs?

Tags: pipe, stdout, stdin, tee

Let's say I want to see the output what a command does, such as `apt-get`. However, if I would run a command redirecting the output such as

```
apt-get install some-application -y > apt_out.txt
```

or

```
apt-get install some-application -y | tee apt_out.txt
```

then I would lose the capability to interact with the program's input. Yet my workaround is to use a `screen -L` session, but would there be something cleaner?

Comment: Unless you specify what you find unclean about using `screen -L`, and what you consider a cleaner option, there is no way to know if an answer will satisfy your condition. E.g. you could select & copy-and-paste the output in your terminal, but whether that is cleaner or not is subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this in terms of feature sets and behaviours rather than some unspecified notion of *cleanliness*.

A *less general-purpose* mechanism than `screen -L`, but that *nonetheless does* for your purposes what `screen` does that `tee` does not (i.e. allow easy interactive use and not make programs drop into their non-interactive or buffered output modes when they find standard output to not be a terminal), is the `script` command.

```
script -c "apt-get install some-application" apt_out.txt
```

A different mechanism to `script` is `ptybandage`, which *is* suitable for use in command pipelines, and *does not* require that its own, outer, standard I/O actually be a terminal.  (Indeed, its primary use case is to make non-interactive standard I/O seem like interactive standard I/O to a child program.)  It is a way to persuade the program to run in its interactive/line buffered mode whilst still using the pipe-through-`tee` approach.

```
ptybandage apt-get install some-application 2>&1 | tee apt_out.txt
```

## Further reading

- [How can I capture stdout/stderr in a file but still see it in my console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362439/)
- [How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/)
- [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/)
- [Why in the output of script (1) the newline is CR + LF (dos-style)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343324/)
- [Remove BS and ESC from Log files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133997/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [*Daniel J. Bernstein's ptyget toolset*](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/bernstein-ptyget.html). Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016).  [*Daniel J. Bernstein's softwares all in one*](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/).  Softwares.

Answer (score 0):

`screen -L` sounds like a good solution to me. Another option is `script` (this logs control characters and mis-typings as well, which some find confusing).

Many programs test to see if their input and output are connected to a terminal or not, and will fail or change their behaviour depending on this.  See `ls` vs. `ls | cat` for a tiny example.